# How to hide if ACF Repeater Sub_field Blank

Tags: php, wordpress, advanced-custom-fields

I'm using ACF pro 5. I create a Repeater Field with two `sub_field`, called `sub_field_item` & `sub_field_value`. I need a code which will hide if `sub_field_value` is empty. Probably `sub_field_item` contains text but if `sub_field_value` empty, then it will hide both.

I tried with this code, but it's not working.

```
<?php
if( have_rows('myrepeater') )
{
    $field_key = "field_5aa18d1bc322c"; //KEY for Repeater main field "myrepeater
    $field = get_field_object($field_key);

    foreach($field['value'] as $value)
    {
    if(!empty($value['sub_field_item']))
        {
        $not_empty = true;
        break;
        }
    }

    if($not_empty == true)
    {
    echo '<h2>' . $field['label'] . '</h2>';
    }

    while ( have_rows('sub_field_item') )
    {                           
    the_row();
    $subfield = get_sub_field('sub_field_value');

        if( !empty($subfield) )
        {
        echo '<b>' . $subfield . '</b>';
        }
    }
}
?>
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

here is the magic code :

```
<?php
if(get_field('field_name')):
    while(has_sub_field('field_name')):
        if(get_sub_field('subfield_name')): ?>
        <h2><?php echo get_sub_field('subfield_name'); ?></h2>
        <?php endif;
    endwhile;
endif;
```